# Use injections in custom scope

Tags: java, scope, cdi, weld, custom-scope

Is it possible to use a `@SessionScoped` bean as a field in a custom scope's Context ?

I am writing a custom scope ("ScreenScoped") with CDI, so that it approximately has the same behavious than CDI's `@ViewScoped` (I do this because the latter is not WebSphere-compatible). So far my scope acts like as `@ApplicationScoped` would. I would like to use my `@SessionScoped NavigationHandler` class, which is called everytime a user clicks a link or button, to determine when my ScreenScoped life-cycle ends. However I do get an error when I try to use an `@Inject`ed field.

```
public class ScreenContext
    implements Context
{
    @Inject
    private NavigationHandler navigationHandler;
    ...
}
```

A NullPointerException appears because of this `@Inject`:

```
16:55:07,492 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-10) Error Rendering View[/page/hello.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /page/hello.xhtml @24,58 visible="#{helloController.popupshowed}": java.lang.NullPointerException

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypackage.scope.screenscope.ScreenContext.get(ScreenContext.java:38) [myproject.jar:]
```

Line 38 is the first time I call the injected field:

```
System.out.println("Navigation is used: " + navigationHandler.getUserId());
```

Comment: Use the BeanManager to get NavigationHandler bean

Comment: As custom context are registered  via Extension, injection can't be performed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject a Bean in `Context`. You need to use the `BeanManager` to access the `NavigationHandler` bean.

Your context is registered via CDI Extension observing `AfterBeanDiscovery` event of CDI lifecycle. That's here that you pass the `BeanManager` to the context :

```
public void afterBeanDiscovery (@Observes final AfterBeanDiscovery event, final BeanManager beanManager)
{
    event.addContext(new ScreenContext(beanManager));
}
```

And then in your `ScreenContext` implementation you can get the `NavigationHandler` bean (in `myMethod` below) using the `BeanManager`:

```
public class ScreenContext implements Context
{

   private final BeanManager m_beanManager;

   public ScreenContext(final BeanManager p_BeanManager)
   {
      m_beanManager = p_BeanManager;
   }

   public void myMethod()
   {
      NavigationHandler NavigationHandlerBean = getNavigationHandler();
      ...
      ...
   }

   private NavigationHandler getNavigationHandler()
   {
      final Set<Bean<?>> beans = m_beanManager.getBeans(NavigationHandler.class);
      final Bean<?> bean = m_beanManager.resolve(beans);

      return (NavigationHandler) m_beanManager.getReference(bean, NavigationHandler.class, m_beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
   }
```

Comment: After testing it, I saw that even though NavigationHandler is WindowScoped, this method always returns the same object when called from two different browsers.

Comment: I re-accepted your answer, as my comment was due to another problem which was resolved in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256767/beanmanager-always-returns-same-reference

Comment: Glad if this helped you :-)