# BeanManager always returns same reference

Tags: hash, scope, cdi, custom-scope

I am creating a custom CDI scope and am using the `BeanManager` to get an injection of my `NavigationHandler` custom class. But the beans it returns are quite strange.

So I use the BeanManager that way :

```
public class ScreenContext implements Context
{
    private NavigationHandler getNavigationHandler()
    {
        final Set<Bean<?>> beans = m_beanManager.getBeans(NavigationHandler.class);
        final Bean<?> bean = m_beanManager.resolve(beans);

        NavigationHandler reference =
            (NavigationHandler) m_beanManager.getReference(bean, NavigationHandler.class,
                m_beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));

        System.out.println("Found "+reference+" (hash="+reference.hashCode()+")");
        return reference;
    }
    ...
}
```

I expect, when I use my project using two different browsers, to get two different `NavigationHandler`, which are defined that way :

```
@Named
@WindowScoped
public class NavigationHandler
    implements Serializable, INavigationHandlerController
```

But my debugger returns `true` when I test `reference1==reference2`. I also get strange hash codes :

```
Found NavigationHandler@593e785f (hash=1261587818)
Found NavigationHandler@b6d51bd (hash=1261587818)
```

I don't understand why the hashes used in the toString() are different, but the hash used in hashCode() are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the reason for these two linked problems, that was a tricky one !

`m_beanManager.getReference(..)` does not return the NavigationHandler instance, but a proxy which is supposed to select and act as the correct NavigationHandler among the existing ones in the scope's context.

**Link to understand the concept of Proxy/Context/BeanManager:** https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies

So my `getNavigationHandler()` method is not suited for the work : my pool which calls this method will hold NavigationHandler proxies instead of NavigationHandlers. Because my pool is not an `@Inject`ed field, the proxy will not get automatically updated by CDI, hence the reference returned is always the one from the last context actively used by a proxy.

For the same reason in this output:

```
Found NavigationHandler@593e785f (hash=1261587818)
Found NavigationHandler@b6d51bd (hash=1261587818)
```

In one case I get the hash of the `NavigationHandler` instance, and in the other case I get the hash of the `NavigationHandler`'s proxy. Yet I don't know which one is which. I am willing to believe the proxy's toString() is used, as `beanManager.getReference(..)` is supposed to serve a new proxy each time, and the hashCode is supposed to be practically unique for object each instances.

**Link that says every instance's hashcode is unique hashcode and cannot change over time:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

So the correct way to implement `getNavigationHandler()` is:

```
private getNavigationHandlergetgetNavigationHandler()
{
    final Set<Bean<?>> beans = m_beanManager.getBeans(getNavigationHandler.class);
    final Bean<?> bean = m_beanManager.resolve(beans);

    /* Works : pure reference (not proxied) */
    Class<? extends Annotation> scopeType = bean.getScope();
    Context context = m_beanManager.getContext(scopeType);
    CreationalContext<?> creationalContext = m_beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    // Casts below are necessary since inheritence does not work for templates
    getNavigationHandler reference =
        context.get((Bean<NavigationHandler>) bean, (CreationalContext<NavigationHandler>) creationalContext);

    return reference;
}
```

**Link that explains the difference between** `beanManager.getReference(..)` **and** `beanManager.getContext(..).get(..)`: [Canonical way to obtain CDI managed bean instance: BeanManager#getReference() vs Context#get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048410/canonical-way-to-obtain-cdi-managed-bean-instance-beanmanagergetreference-vs?answertab=active#tab-top)